# Minimum of folded normal distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, convergence, folded-normal-distribution

If we draw independent samples $x_0\sim N(0,\sigma^2), x_i \sim N(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$
for $i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, N-1\}$, what is the probability that $|x_0|$ is the smallest among all samples $|x_i|$'s? Under what condition is $|x_0|$ the smallest almost surely?

I was trying to calculate $\mathbb{P}[|x_0|<|x_i|]$ for some $i$. Following the suggestion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803421/probability-that-one-folded-normal-is-bigger-than-another), I get the probability $(1−\Phi(\frac{−\mu_i}{2\sigma}))(1−\Phi(\frac{−\mu_i}{\sigma}))+(1−\Phi(\frac{−\mu_i}{2\sigma}))\Phi(−\frac{\mu_i}{\sigma})$. But I'm not sure if it is the right approach.

Comment: What does the notation "$i \in [N - 1]$" mean?

Comment: Edited. It means $i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, N-1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Are $X_0, X_1, \ldots, X_{N - 1}$ independent?

Comment: Yes, they are independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Phi_{\mu, \sigma^2}, \varphi_{\mu, \sigma^2}$ denote the CDF and pdf of a $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ random variable respectively.  In particular, denote $\Phi_{0, 1}$ and $\varphi_{0, 1}$ by $\Phi$ and $\varphi$. Clearly, we have
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{\mu, \sigma^2}(x) = \sigma^{-1}\varphi(\sigma^{-1}(x - \mu)), \;
\Phi_{\mu, \sigma^2}(x) = \Phi(\sigma^{-1}(x - \mu)).
\end{align*}

Your calculation of $P[|X_i| > |X_0|]$ for some $i$ is incorrect.  By independence of $X_0$ and $X_i$, the correct result should be
\begin{align}
& P[|X_i| > |X_0|] \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty P[|X_i| > |x|]\varphi_{0, \sigma^2}(x)dx \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty (P[X_i > |x|] + P[X_i < -|x|])\varphi_{0, \sigma^2}(x)dx \\
=& \frac{1}{\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty[\Phi(-\sigma^{-1}(|x| -\mu_i)) + \Phi(-\sigma^{-1}(|x| + \mu_i))]\varphi(\sigma^{-1}x)dx. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Unless $\mu_i = 0$, a closed-form of the integral $(1)$ is unavailable.  When $\mu_i = 0$, $(1)$ can be further simplified to $1/2$, which meets the intuition.

Similarly, it can be shown that
\begin{align*}
& P[|X_1| > |X_0|, \ldots, |X_{N - 1}| > |X_0|] \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{i = 1}^{N - 1}P[|X_i| > |x|]\varphi_{0, \sigma^2}(x)dx \\
=& \frac{1}{\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\prod_{i = 1}^{N - 1}[\Phi(-\sigma^{-1}(|x| -\mu_i)) + \Phi(-\sigma^{-1}(|x| + \mu_i))]\varphi(\sigma^{-1}x)dx. 
\end{align*}

To show that $|X_0|$ cannot be the smallest almost surely, it is equivalent to show that the probability $P[|X_0| < \min(|X_1|, \ldots, |X_{N - 1}|)] < 1$, or $P[|X_0| \geq \min(|X_1|, \ldots, |X_{N - 1}|)] > 0$, which would be implied by $P[|X_0| \geq |X_i|] > 0$ for some $i$.  Evaluating this probability is almost the same as obtaining $(1)$:
\begin{align}
P[|X_i| \leq |X_0|] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P[|X_i| \leq |x|]\varphi_{0, \sigma^2}(x)dx. \tag{2}
\end{align}
By Theorem 15.2(ii) in *Probability and Measure* by Patrick Billingsley, to show that $(2)$ is strictly positive, it suffices to show the integrand $f(x) := P[|X_i| \leq |x|]\varphi_{0, \sigma^2}(x) > 0$ on a set with positive Lebesgue measure. Since $\varphi_{\mu_i, \sigma^2}(t) > 0$ for all $t$, if $x \neq 0$, then
\begin{align*}
P[|X_i| \leq |x|] = 
P[-|x| \leq X_i \leq |x|] = 
\int_{-|x|}^{|x|}\varphi_{\mu_i, \sigma^2}(t)dt > 0.
\end{align*}
In addition, $\varphi_{0, \sigma^2}(x) > 0$ everywhere. Hence $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$.  This completes the proof.

Comment: This is neat work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain why the integral (2) is always strictly positive so there's no way $|X_0|$ is the smallest almost surely? integral (2) is essentially P[|X_i|>|X_0|]. I don't find anything problematic if P[|X_i|>|X_0|] > 0.

Comment: @Anonny You're absolutely right.  I've updated my answer.